# JavaScript: Have to click the login button twice for email to appear

Tags: javascript, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my app, the user will input nickname and password. It will search for corresponding email in Firebase Database and use Firebase to sign in.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="" id="nickname" placeholder="nickname">
<input type="password" name="" id="pass" placeholder="******">
<input type='submit' onclick="Login();" value="Sign in" id="sign" class="btn">
```

JavaScript:

```
function Login() {
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').value;
    const pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    var emails;
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("userlist").child(nickname).on("value", function(snapshot) {
        emails = snapshot.val().email;
    });
    const connect = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emails, pass).then(function() {

        alert(" You are now logged in.");
        sessionStorage.setItem("nickname", nickname);
    });
}
```

The problem is very clear. The first time you click the login button, email address recorded by snapshot function is still undefined. You have to click the button again, for the second time, for email address to be recorded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should do the trick.

Since you only need to read the value of the `nickname` database node once, use the [once()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data_once) method. When the `then()` handler is called, after the promise returned by `once()` resolves, you can get the `emails` value and use it as an argument of  the `signInWithEmailAndPassword()` method.

```
function Login() {
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const nickname = document.getElementById('nickname').value;
    const pass = document.getElementById('pass').value;
    var emails;
    const ref = firebase.database().ref("userlist").child(nickname);
    return ref.once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        emails = snapshot.val().email;
        return auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(emails, pass);
    })
    .then(function() {
        alert(" You are now logged in.");
        sessionStorage.setItem("nickname", nickname);
    });
}
```

Comment: @CSDUG I see you have accepted the answer, glad that I could help. If you think my answer helped you, you may upvote it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
<input type='submit' onclick="Login();" value="Sign in" id="sign" class="btn">
```

to this:

```
<input type='submit' (onclick)="Login();" value="Sign in" id="sign" class="btn">
```

Comment: This is not a good Stack Overflow answer (even if it winds up solving the OPs problem) because it does not explain what the problem was or how your solution solved it. As it is now, it should be a comment. Please read **["How to Answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**